# Why is my log4j class only logging FATAL messages?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have the following log4j Java class:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("pre_loggerDOTinfo");
        System.out.println();
        //logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);   //used to be.. 

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.warn("Hello, this is an WARN  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #2");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #3");
        logger.fatal("Hello, this is an FATAL  message ALSO, #4");
        logger.debug("Hello, this is an FATAL  message");

        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        logger.info("Hello, this is an INFO message");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("post_loggerDOTinfo");

    }

}
```

And in the same directory, I have a log4j properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, Console


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= C:\\Users\\adel\\Desktop\\Misc_Stuff\\Java_Code\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

As you can see, I commented out the `logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL)` code, as it caused my program to crash (said it can't find setLevel, and even when I tried toLevel it did not work)

My output is this :

> pre_loggerDOTinfo
>
> 16:47:09.575 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message 16:47:09.575 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL
>   message ALSO, #2
>
> 16:47:09.575 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #3
>
> 16:47:09.575 [main] FATAL HelloWorld - Hello, this is an FATAL 
>   message ALSO, #4
>
> post_loggerDOTinfo

I'm a little confused about which properties file is being used in my class. Is there a way to trace back the version of log4j I use, and where it gets the log4j properties info?

any tips appreciated, thanks !~

Comment: have you initialized the `-Dlog4j.configuration=` property?

Comment: Which jars do you have in your classpath?

Comment: Are you using `log4j2` or `log4j`? Where exactly is the `log4j.properties` file? Is the appender name `file` or `Console`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -  I believe the appender name is Console

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - in my path (when I run "set path" in CMD) , I see - `C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar`  ,  and in classpath I see - `C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar;C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar` ,

Comment: @Sebas - Not sure what this means, let me look into that. thanks !

Comment: You've declared the `rootLogger` to use a non-configured appender named `Console`, but have named and configured an appender `file`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Ok, I think I see what you mean .  I'm on it , Thanks very much !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application uses log4j2 classes (the package is `org.apache.logging.log4j`, while log4j-1.x is in the `org.apache.log4j` namespace).

However, your configuration is a properties file aiming at log4j-1.x.

Log4j2 does not understand properties file-based configurations. You must provide an XML (or Jason or YAML) configuration file. Log4j2 will look for a config file named **log4j2.xml** in the classpath. If you put it elsewhere you need to tell log4j2 the path using the `log4j.configurationFile` system property.

The log4j2 [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html) has many examples configurations (the docs are much better than for log4j-1.x); I suggest starting with the example config shown for the [RollingFile appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

If Log4j2 cannot find a configuration it will use a default config that only logs at ERROR and FATAL level to the console.

Finally, be aware that with log4j2, you [need](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars) both the log4j-api and the log4j-core jar files in the classpath.

Comment: As of version 2.4, Log4j now supports configuration via properties files. see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ, make sure that the log4j2.xml are placed at the src/main/resource folder. If project only logs FATAL messages, that often mean that you placed the log4j2.xml file at the wrong location (or there are 2 files with same name at different locations in the project, etc) and framework log4j could not find it and prints FATAL messages only as default.

```
project (root)
|_src
  |_main
    |_java
    |_resource (add log4j2.xml here)
  |_test
    |_java
    |_resource
```

I am using IntelliJ, latest log4j-core and taken config file examples from:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Comment: I did not manage to get the log4j.properties file to work (with moderate effort), there for I stuck with the xml file.